# Random letters from a random word

Tags: javascript, html, random

I have 4 words, 4 letters in each word. I need to choose 1 word from those 4 words.  With that 1 word, I need to randomize the letter order and put it into draggable box.  I then need to drag that box in to proper order.

This is for generating random word from array:

```
 var myShows = ['coco','bobo','lolo','popo'];
 var show = myShows[Math.floor(Math.random() * myShows.length)];
```

I don't know how to randomize letters place from generated random word:

```
function handleDragStart(e) {
                e.dataTransfer.setData("text", this.id);
            }
            function handleDragEnterLeave(e) {
                if (e.type == "dragenter") {
                    this.className = "drag-enter";
                } else {
                    this.className = "";
                }
            }
            function handleOverDrop(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                if (e.type != "drop") {
                    return;
                }
                var draggedId = e.dataTransfer.getData("text");
                var draggedEl = document.getElementById(draggedId);
                if (draggedEl.parentNode == this) {
                    return;
                }
                draggedEl.parentNode.removeChild(draggedEl);
                this.appendChild(draggedEl);
                this.className = "";
            }
            window.onload = function () {


                var myShows = ['coco','bobo','lolo','popo'];
                var show = myShows[Math.floor(Math.random() * myShows.length)];
                //document.write(show);
              /*i'd tried this below code to generate random letter but it just working in log,
              how would i use that to store*/
for (var i = 0; i < show.length; i++) {
  console.log(show.charAt(i));
    //document.write(show.charAt(i));
}
               // document.randform.rf.value=show;

                var draggable = document.querySelectorAll("[draggable]");
                var targets = document.querySelectorAll("[data-drop-target]");
                for (var i = 0; i < draggable.length; i++) {
                    draggable[i].addEventListener("dragstart", handleDragStart);
                }
                for (i = 0; i < targets.length; i++) {
                    targets[i].addEventListener("dragover", handleOverDrop);
                    targets[i].addEventListener("drop", handleOverDrop);
                    targets[i].addEventListener("dragenter", handleDragEnterLeave);
                    targets[i].addEventListener("dragleave", handleDragEnterLeave);
                }
            };
```

This is my HTML body:

```
  <div class="panel">
                    <div data-drop-target="true"></div>
                    <div data-drop-target="true"></div>
                    <div data-drop-target="true"></div>
                    <div data-drop-target="true"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel" >
                    <div data-drop-target="true" draggable="true" ></div>
                    <div data-drop-target="true" draggable="true"> </div>
                   <div data-drop-target="true" draggable="true"> </div>
                    <div data-drop-target="true" draggable="true"> </div>
                </div>
```

So how would I save the original word and compare it with the dragged box?

Comment: can u provide any plunker?

Comment: Use a global variable to store the chosen word. Use `string.split('')` to split the word up into an array and then (in a loop) randomly pick a character from that array, set it in the next free/open box and remove it from the array. When the array is empty, you continue. When checking, just get the contents of every box that is placed (in order) and check if that makes the word stored in the global variable.